# Updating raw with primary auto incremented column

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite, sqlite

I have a table where i am storing latitude and longitude. My table schema is following

```
TestId | Latitude | Longitude | TestName |
```

where testid is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT.

Now if table exists same latitude and longitude then previous raw should be updated. I am doing as folloing.

add all value to content

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put(GLNetTestDataContract.TestPinRecord.COLUMN_NAME_TESTNAME, testName);
values.put(GLNetTestDataContract.TestPinRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LATTITUDE, lattitude);
values.put(GLNetTestDataContract.TestPinRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LATTITUDE, lattitude);
```

/**Check for latitude and longitude value if exists in table then update the test*/

```
        String selectionCheckLatitudeAndLongitude = Gaurav.TestRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LATTITUDE + "=? AND " +
                                            Gaurav.TestRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LATTITUDE + "=?";

        String[] selectionArgslCheckLatitudeAndLongitude = { String.valueOf(lattitude),String.valueOf(longitude)};
        try{
        newRowId = mDatabase.update(GLNetTestDataContract.TestPinRecord.TABLE_NAME, values, selectionCheckLatitudeAndLongitude, selectionArgslCheckLatitudeAndLongitude);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            mLogger.printLog("pin", "Exception while updating");
            mLogger.printLog("pin", e.getMessage());
        }
if(newRowId>0)
            mLogger.printLog("pin","Test updated with existing geo location");
        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        else
        {
            newRowId = mDatabase.insert(GLNetTestDataContract.TestPinRecord.TABLE_NAME,null, values);
            mLogger.printLog("pin","Test inserted with existing geo location");
        }
```

it always return 0. that mean raw is not updating. What am i doing wrong. any pointer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for the same column twice

```
Gaurav.TestRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LATTITUDE + "=? AND " +
Gaurav.TestRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LATTITUDE + "=?";
```

Should be:

```
Gaurav.TestRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LATTITUDE + "=? AND " +
Gaurav.TestRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LONGITUDE + "=?";
```

Also in your `put` statement:

```
values.put(GLNetTestDataContract.TestPinRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LATTITUDE, lattitude);
values.put(GLNetTestDataContract.TestPinRecord.COLUMN_NAME_LONGITUDE, longitude);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken much appreciated i could not notice these mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem - sometimes you look at the code for so long you cannot see it :)